# Magento AHT Slideshow plugin - Fatal error: Call to a member function setProductsRelated() on a non-object

Tags: php, magento

We are using the AHT magento plugin to manage slideshows, and when selecting the static blocks menu item on the left, we get this error:

`Fatal error: Call to a member function setProductsRelated() on a non-object in /www/app/code/local/AHT/Aslideshow/controllers/Adminhtml/SlideshowController.php on line 270`

The line in question looks like this (the getLayout one):

`public function staticblockAction()
{

$this->_initAction();

$this->loadLayout();

$this->getLayout()->getBlock('aslideshow.slideshow.edit.tab.staticblocks')
            ->setProductsRelated($this->getRequest()->getPost('staticblocks_slideshow', null));

$this->renderLayout();

}
`

[image: The Static block error]

Comment: I don't know this module but this error is basically saying that the object represented by block 'aslideshow.slideshow.edit.tab.staticblocks' hasn't been initialized yet. If I were you, I'd probably make sure if you didn't miss any step of setting up the module before you try to view the static blocks.

Comment: Thanks, is the name of the block any indication where I can find it? Or is it just a name?